# How to make String.fromCharCode accept values of space as input?

Tags: javascript, html, string, user-input

I have this code

```
<script>
    function isInputCharacter(evt){
      var ch = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);

      if(!(/[1-6,A-Z]/.test(ch))){
        evt.preventDefault();
        }      
    }
  </script>
```

but it does not accept the values of space. Means it will only accept if I entered 'LEVEL1' but does not accept when I type 'LEVEL 1'. How to make it accept the space between the words?

Comment: So you're currently accepting all uppercase letters, digits 1-6, and commas. Just add a space to that list.

Comment: Can you please add some examples of what is and is not valid

Comment: @Phil it will accept all the number 1,2,3,4,5,6 and all uppercase A-Z but if you entered a lowercase a-z and any other keys it will not be valid. So if I want to add the space, I should write it like this `/[1-6,A-Z,' ']/` am I right @Robby Cornelissen ?

Comment: How many spaces is valid though? What about if it was only spaces? This is why I asked for examples. FYI, doesn't sound like you want to allow commas so you should omit those from your character class. If you're looking for invalid characters, you should invert the class, ie `if (/[^A-Z1-6 ]/.test(ch))`

Comment: @phil it works if I type 'LEVEL 1 LEVEL 2' and also if I were to types spaces only. Yes, I made a mistake there allowing the commas. I thought the commas was to separate the two condition. thanks :)